# Yii - CHtml; Difference between active form input and normal form input

Tags: yii, yii-chtml

Quite simply, what is the difference between using `CHtml::textField` or `CHtml::activeTextField`, as well as other Yii CHtml form inputs.

When is it appropriate to use active vs normal form inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The non-active versions are used without a model reference. The active versions all take
a model instance as their ﬁrst argument.

By having a model instance tied to the form each field has the model's definition, its labels, validation routines tied to the form. It also will be pre-populate fields when updating data.